# While Using Static Pages, How Can I Get /blog into the URL of Each Post?

Tags: plugins, functions, urls, options, configuration

I have Wordpress installed on the root of my website. It is using a static homepage and posts page. As it stands, each post will look like this example.com/blogpostname.

I don't want to use category workaround where you set the default post's category to blog, it seems more like a workaround than a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In admin under `Settings > Permalinks`, select `Custom Structure` and enter `/blog/%postname%/`.

This will prepend `/blog/` to categories and tags by default, and any custom post types and taxonomies where you have not registered them with the `with_front` argument set to `false`. you can remove it from the built-in category and tag taxonomies by setting category base and tag base (also under Settings > Permalinks) to `category` and `tag`, respectively (or whatever you want your bases to be). The end result will be that only posts will contain the `blog` prefix.

Comment: Won't that be site-wide though, not only on blog posts?

Comment: it will be prepended to categories and tags by default, and any custom post types and taxonomies where you have not registered them with the `with_front` argument set to `false`. you can remove it from the built-in category and tag taxonomies by setting category base and tag base (also under Settings > permalinks) to `category` and `tag`, respectively (or whatever you want your bases to be). the end result will be that only posts will contain the `blog` prefix.