# how do i add posts-page slug before posts slug in permalinks

Tags: posts, permalinks, slug

I have a posts page and the page slug is /blog

my current permalink structure is /%postname%/

when i click on a blog post. say for example the posts slug is adrenaline-rush

the url is www.siteurl/adrenaline-rush

what i am trying to achieve is www.siteurl/blog/adrenaline-rush

how would i go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you made your permalinks `/blog/%postname%/`?

Comment: wouldnt that make all my other pages have /blog prefixed?

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129344/4771)

Comment: I think it will only make other "post"-like items have the prefix, ie, any custom post types you defined which have 'capability_type' => 'post'. However for those you can set disable the /blob/ prefix with: 'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false )

Comment: Thanks for responding. it does work. I was worried it was going to break my custom posts but i do have them set up with specific slugs. can you put that comment into a answer box so i can accept you as the answer please :)